# How do I wait for a javascript function to return a response using Chrome.storage API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the following code to set and get name value pairs in a Chrome Extension.

```
if (!this.Chrome_getValue || (this.Chrome_getValue.toString && this.Chrome_getValue.toString().indexOf("not supported") > -1)) {
    this.Chrome_getValue = function (key, def) {
        chrome.storage.local.get(key, function (result) {
            return result[key];
        });
    };
    this.Chrome_setValue = function (key, value) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[key] = value;
        return chrome.storage.local.set(obj)
    }
}
```

I am then invoking these as follows:

```
Chrome_setValue("City", "London");

var keyValue = Chrome_getValue("City");
```

The problem is the keyValue is always 'undefined' even if I put a 1 second delay in trying to read back the value. I understand this is because the 'chrome.storage.local.get' function is asynchronous.. the following code works fine.

```
Chrome_setValue("City", "London");

chrome.storage.local.get("City", function (result) {
     alert(result["City"]);
});
```

Is there any way when binding the keyValue (using `get`) I can force the code to wait for the function to return a response? Or perhaps I'm approaching this from the wrong angle. Essentially I am looking for a way I can abstract out the `set` and `get` methods for handling data within the chrome.storage framework? Ideally two simple functions I can call for setting and retrieving name value pairs.

Before I was using localStorage which was very straightforward.

```
//Set
localStorage["City"] = "London";

//Get
var keyValue = localStorage["City"];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QF_D, I'm into educated guesswork here, so be prepared for this not to work first time .....

..... here goes :

```
if (!this.Chrome_getValue || (this.Chrome_getValue.toString && this.Chrome_getValue.toString().indexOf("not supported") > -1)) {
    this.Chrome_getValue = function (key, def) {
        var dfrd = $.Deferred();
        chrome.storage.local.get(key, function (result) {
            dfrd.resolve(result[key]);
        });
        return dfrd.promise();
    };
    this.Chrome_setValue = function (key, value) {
        var dfrd = $.Deferred();
        var obj = {};
        obj[key] = value;
        var listen = function(changes, namespace) {
            dfrd.resolve(changes[key]);
            chrome.storage.onChanged.removeListener(listen);//remove, to prevent accumulation of listeners
        }
        chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(listen);
        chrome.storage.local.set(obj);
        return dfrd.promise()
    }
}
```

The get and set functions should thus return jQuery promises. The promise returned by the set function is resolved with a `StorageChange` object defined [here](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html). In general you won't need this object, rather just respond to the promise being resolved.

Everything above is untested. I'm not too sure about :

- `chrome.storage.onChanged....`. Should it be `chrome.storage.local.onChanged....`?
- `.removeListener()`. It seems resonable that it should exist if `addListener` exists, though I can't find any evidence of it.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot, that's very constructive! After posting this however I started to wonder if I was over-thinking this problem. Effectively I need my Chrome Extension to persist data from subdomain1.website.com to subdomain2.website.com, something localStorage doesn't do. Many solutions mention using a background.js so I am now exploring this avenue.

Comment: Incidentally any method in Chrome for storing variables relies on an async function! So there's no getting away from using the $.Deferred() method you describe above. The problem I'm having is figuring out what to do with the returned dfrd.promise() object...How can I find the value from this?

Comment: [This](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) is probably the best start point for learning about Deferreds and Promises. To work with a value with which a Deferred (and hence a Promise derived from it) is resoved, create handlers (functions) as parameters to the `.then()` or `.done()` methods.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's essentially because the `chrome.storage` API is *asynchronous*. You are facing something which is at the core of JavaScript.

What's executed in the `chrome.storage.get` callback **is not returned** by `chrome.storage.get`. You have 2 ways of dealing with it:

- deal with the storage value in the callback
- use the Promise pattern to keep your code *feeling* synchronous (cf. the previous answer)

You really have to figure out the difference between **synchronous** and **asynchronous**.